# My low-profile video card does not fit in my mini tower, what can I do?

Tags: video, graphics-card, pci-express, mini-itx

GPU: ASUS ENGT430

PC: Dell Vostro mini 230

What it looks like:

[image]

Even though I installed the card, I can't close the lid now. Any way around it?

Answer (score 5):

From ASUS's site: http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/NVIDIA_Series/ENGT430DI1GD3LP/

- Unscrew your "large" metal plate (2 sets of 2 hex screws around DVI and VGA ports, pliers will do, and one phillips screw above the HDMI port).
- Screw in the 2 small metal plates that should've come with the card ( http://www.asus.com/websites/Global/products/oFWUy4OBqyNgtdmZ/QV5rfRIW0i5WAl2F_500.jpg )

Alternative: get out your dremel / drill + cutting disk.